# MongoDB - Pessimistic Locking of a Collection

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, performance, locking

I would greatly appreciate your time and creative input in perhaps guiding me in general direction on something I've been trying to figure out.

I have intentions of allowing users to manipulate a collection on an order-by-order basis. It is a stock market based application, so I have determined that it is crucial to do it in this fashion. When a user places some sort of order on a stock, I need it to execute order-by-order, and a single order is the equivalent of one single document in a stock's collection. The order queue would then be available for more orders after the previous one has been completed. I have attempted to implement some manual locking methods, but I still run into the problem of orders executing on orders that are not next in the order queue.

```
var stringType = "locked";
var checkIt = await stocksLS.collection(data[5]).findOneAndUpdate({"editor": {$exists:false}},
{$set: {editor: [stringType]}},
{
sort:{"Price":1,"TS":1}
}
);
```

In this snippet of code, data[5] is just the ticker symbol of a stock, then I throw a lock on the next best order (sorted by lowest price and earliest timestamp) to ensure that order gets executed on solely by one user. However, if multiple users execute an order simultaneously, it obviously just starts executing on future orders that are further and further away from the next best order which is not intended (since they are still not locked per this code).

My best solution would be to just place a lock on all of the documents while an order executes and then have incoming orders try to queue the order queue collection repeatedly until it attaches a lock.

There is likely a much better solution to this all, but it is the best I have come up with, so I would appreciate your input on the matter to get guided toward better ideas and solutions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a queue, use a queue. An actual one. Find a queue library in the language of your choice (JS).

You could attempt to *implement* a queue, but instead of fighting all of the bugs that will inevitably pop up just use an already existing, debugged one.

MongoDB is not a queue, nor does it implement a queue in the server.