# Mongodb lock collection until flag is set?

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple collection with pre populated generated ids.

```
|task_id| used|
|      1| true|
|      2|false|
|      3|false|
```

The idea is that i have a simple method that returns next **task_id**. `getNextTaskId()`, that sets used to true and returns **task_id**. But there might be concurrent calls for this method. How can i lock collection to prevent method from returning same **task_id** twice and prevent updating used to true twice, or more (for the same **task_id**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the most appropriate approach for that case is using of **Compound Operations**.

For example, you can use something like this:

```js
db.tasks.findOneAndUpdate({"used": {$ne: true}}, {$set: {"used": true}})
```

Implementations:

- [Java](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/crud/compound-operations/)
- [Go](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/crud/compound-operations/)
- [NodeJS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/compound-operations/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB does not provide a "lock collection" operation, because the database is designed for concurrency (and scale) and locking prevents both. There are various other strategies provided to satisfy various use cases.

See:

- [MongoDB concurrent update to same document is not behaving atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915366/mongodb-concurrent-update-to-same-document-is-not-behaving-atomic/65915837#65915837)
- [MongoDB - Pessimistic Locking of a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483778/mongodb-pessimistic-locking-of-a-collection/66484240#66484240)
- [how to lock pymongo collection to reading & writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943426/how-to-lock-pymongo-collection-to-reading-writing/65945312#65945312)

etc.

If you want a queue, use a queueing library in your language.