# Perform mutually exclusive Read & Write operations on a mongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

I've a program which needs to have two processes doing mutually exclusive reads and writes to a mongodb document.

One part (lets call it **"process_a"**) reads and updates (adds) to the document. The other (lets call it **"process_b"**) reads and updates (deletes) all the values to the document.

So in an ideal scenario, process_a's read and writes never overlaps with process_b's read and writes.

Otherwise, if the **process_b**'s reads right before the **process_a** updates the document with new values. **Process_b** would delete (set it to zero) the document without realizing the update from **process_a** every happened. Thus failing to record the transaction.

Is there any way to lock the document/collection while one process performs its read and update task.

Comment: You could add a locking table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67262163/mongodb-lock-collection-until-flag-is-set/67263209#67263209

Comment: @scenox thanks for the info man. but im really a noob when it comes to redis. Can u please elaborate on this idea of locking table ?? coz i didn't find any tables under redis or a way to lock it. Thanks. Waiting impatiently :)

Comment: Redis? That's a new information :-)

Comment: sorry I missed that this question was for mongoDB. I wrote redis cause i ultimately when with it. anyhooo thanks @scenox for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

I found no way of doing it with 100% certainty. So I ended up modifying code somewhere  else to prevent it from happening.